# Post quit() to QEventLoop before exec()

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I create a `QEventLoop` object and trying to put `quit()` message before starting it so my intention is to enter and quit a loop:

```
QEventLoop loop;
loop.connect(this, SIGNAL(sig()), SLOT(quit()));
emit sig();
loop.exec(); // can't get past this point
```

But thread is cycling in loop and never quits ...
How can I achieve  intended behaviour ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @thuga I want to call `post()` and `get()` of `QNetworkAccessManager` from different threads. But these methods are need to be called from the owning thread. So I create `wrapperClass` which contains `QNetworkAccessManager`. And when user calls `wrapper.sendPostRequest(...)` my thread should wait for `QNetworkAccessManager` to execute the call and after that I can continue. Loops seemed like a reasonable way to pause thread and wait for 'wake up' signal ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This in isolation doesn't appear to make much sense, but to provide an answer to your very question, you can connect with `Qt::QueuedConnection` and then the `quit` call will be received when running the event loop and then the loop will quit correctly.

This works because slots are executed in order of the `connect` calls, so another slot that too happens to be connected to `sig()` can do whatever it wants, even start an own event loop. However, the last connection is yours, and its queued call to `quit` will happen last with no other event loop action in between the queued call to `quit` and the call to `loop.exec`.

Remember that local `QEventLoops`, just like calls to `QApplication::processEvents`, are very dangerous. If you can change the code, try to setup a statemachine to do asynchronous work.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will test your suggestions little later and mark the answer if it work. I added explanation why I chose `QEventLoop` in the comment to the question, what do you think ? %)